# UICollectionView doesn't work when is in tab bar item

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

This is my first question here so sorry if I'm not clear.

I have 3 colletionviews inside a view. Each collectionview cell has a label inside, this view is a tabbar item, when i delete the relashionship with tabbar, my collectionview work perfectly, but when the relashionship exists, my collectionview cell's label doesn't work. I'm sending prints:

Relationship exists here;

[image]

No Relationship;

[image]

Somene knows why this happens? and what Can I do do solve?

Thanks

Comment: Formatting & spelling

Answer (score -1):

I solved that embeded the viewcontroller(s) that wasn't appearing in a navigation.

Explaining what fix to me:

I don't know why this fix. What I've just selected the view with collection view inside choose Editor>Embeded in>Navigation Controller

Just that worked.

Comment: It's good to know that you solved it.  Could you [edit] your answer to provide a bit more explanation, to help others who may be struggling with the same problem?